# How do I repair a large area at side & bottom of external door

Tags: doors

My dog chewed completed through the bottom and opening side of our back door.  It is like she has created a pet door for a very small pet.  It is approx. 15cm x 15cm.  As a temporary measure to stop rodents & the like getting in I screwed a thin piece of timber on the inside.  The door is a filled door not hollow (except where the dog chewed??)

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange . Are you asking how to keep critters / rodents out with a hole in your door? The quick and easy way would be to screw or glue a thin panel to the outside of the door.

Comment: No I have already screwed a thin piece of timber to door but it is a rental house & apart from replacing the whole door I wondered if I could do something else to fix the "gap" and then repaint the area.  I would like to get my bond back.

Comment: Also because the dog chewed the side and bottom edge there isn't a lot to adher something to if you follow my line of thought.

Comment: If you wanted the bond back, you should probably have prevented the damage from occurring. A non-obvious repair is not going to be easy. Best suggestion I have short of some fairly sophisticated woodworking is to drive some screws into that area as anchors to support an epoxy/Bondo reconstruction attempt... but I am not convinced that won't make a bad situation worse.

Answer (score 3):

The only really practical solution here is to replace the door. If the dog has also chewed up the door framing in addition to the door then replacement of the door jamb and trimming is also in task list.

After the replacements are in place make sure you address what has led the dog to do this. It is my experience that the animal is probably exhibiting this behavior because they are bored or have been confined to a small area behind the door where the chewing is taking place.